Best sequence has just two elements.
Let $\mathcal A_{s}$ be the set of sequences $X=(x_m)_{m \in I}$ where $I=\{1,2,...,n\}$ with $n \ge 2$ and possibly $n =\infty$ is an index set with $x_1=0$, $x_2=s>0$ and $x_m>x_{m-1}$ for $m,m-1 \in I.$ In addition, we require that the sequence $X$ satisfies
$$ \sum_{m \in I} e^{-\gamma x_m}<\infty \text{ for all }\gamma>0.$$
We then fix $x_2=s>0$ (as $x_1=0$ is always fixed) and define $\gamma(X,\lambda)>0$ for $\lambda \in (0,x_2)$ by the condition
$$ \sum_{m \in I} (\lambda-x_m) e^{-\gamma(X,\lambda) x_m}=0.$$
Based on some examples, I then claim that for $\lambda \in (0,s)$
$$\max_{X\in \mathcal A_s} \sum_{m \in I} e^{-\gamma(X,\lambda) x_m} $$
is attained for the sequence $X=(0,s)$, i.e. $I=\{1,2\}$ such that
$$\max_{X\in \mathcal A_s} \sum_{m \in I} e^{-\gamma(X,\lambda) x_m}  = 1 + e^{-\gamma((0,s),\lambda)s}.$$
This claim is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{m \in I} e^{-\gamma(X,\lambda) x_m} \le (1-\lambda/s)^{-1}$$
for any $X \in \mathcal A_s$ and $\lambda \in (0,s).$

I cross-posted this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480742/extremizing-sequence-consists-of-two-elements

To mark the question answered I copied below my answer to the MathOverflow crosspost of the question.
The question is very easy.
Indeed, put $\gamma=\gamma(X,\lambda)$ and $S=\sum_{m \in I} e^{-\gamma x_m}$.
The equality
$$ \sum_{m \in I} (\lambda-x_m) e^{-\gamma x_m}=0$$
implies
$$\lambda S=\sum_{m \in I} \lambda e^{-\gamma x_m}=
\sum_{m \in I\setminus\{1\}} x_m e^{-\gamma x_m}\ge
\sum_{m \in I\setminus\{1\}} s e^{-\gamma x_m}=s(S-1)$$
Therefore $S\le \frac s{s-\lambda}=(1-\lambda/s)^{-1}$.
